# Office URI Fails to Open in Word when using S3 PreignedURL

Tags: amazon-s3, ms-word, uri, ms-office

I'm attempting to allow a user in a web application  to download a Word document and open it directly in Word. We store our files in AWS S3. As such, I am thinking I can use the Office URI Schemes to do so. I'd provide a S3 presigned URL and let Word take care of the rest.

I'm running into an issue where Word can't open the file. I get a dialog in Word that says "Sorry, we couldn't open ". I'm lost where to start debugging. Is this even possible?

```
<a href="ms-word:ofe|u|https://some-test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.docx?<more presignedURL"> Open in Word </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When Word attempts to open the file, it looks like it fetches it not with a simple HTTP GET, but instead using the WebDAV protocol, which of course presigned URLs do not support.

I decided to use [Milton](https://milton.io/) to serve files stored in S3 through WebDAV.